# menuIcon not showing

Tags: pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

I'm building my first watchface for pebble and everything has built pretty good now I'm trying to pretty it up and add a menuIcon so it's not a blank image when I look in the pebble app drawer. Needless to say I ran into a bit of a snag and I can't seem to get the menu image to load. Everything builds and installs nicely though. Code is [here](https://github.com/cartyc/simpleTimeVertical)

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your icon is in greyscale, not black and white (1-bit). Try converting it to 1-bit and building again.

Comment: Hi Chris. That solved a future problem I was wondering about, the watchface now shows when browsing on the pebble. I am still having trouble getting it to show on the phone in the app locker. Either way you helped me greatly. Many thanks!

Comment: Just found the answer to that issue, I need to have my watchface in the store rather just via the sdk,

Comment: @macintoshPrime could you please cite where you found this? it would help :)

Comment: Hi Ryan, my memory is a little fuzzy on where I got the details but I will try to find it for you.  For the meantime to the best of my recollection the problem was that the menu icon was being provided from the pebble store and not via the sdk and that's why it wouldn't show for me. Not sure how things roll on the new versions though, I haven't had time to do much pebbling as of late.